# Silverlight/WPF - making a grid editor

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

Im making an application where i want to provide the user with the ability to design a layout. The application is for digital signage so i need the user to be able to split the screen in some regions. I'm considering using a grid for this but i cant wrap my mind around providing this edit functionality. Should be a basic grid, adding/removing columns, having /col/row spans and then aligning them.

Any ideas on how to proceed with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the usual Grid control with some [GridSplitters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridsplitter%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to change the columns width/height. [Take a look at this demo](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-the-GridSplitter-control-in-Silverlight-2-Beta-1.aspx). When removing a row/column I would set the width/height to 0. When adding a new row/column, just add a new RowDefinition/ColumnDefinition to the Grid. Is this feasible?